Should we get rid of programming-language related tags?
We‘ve got several programming-language related tags. For example: java and javascript
Considering that we‘ve got a close-reason reading 

Off Topic – Programming questions are off-topic even if you are writing or debugging cryptographic code. Unless your question is specifically about how the cryptographic algorithm or protocol works, you should look into asking on Stack Overflow instead.

using such programming-related tags could send the wrong message to users; especially to new users who don’t tend to read our help center. 
After having checked several Q&As that use such tags, it shows the related Q&As could well do without those tags – at least, from my perspective. I also stumbled upon the fact that there are no c or cpp tags either, which seems to underline that tags like java, javascript, … might indeed be nothing but superfluous.
What’s your point of view?

Remove those programming-language related tags because we don’t really need them, or
Keep those tags because…


One reason I could imagine is to deal with special quirks some language's crypto libraries do, but then again such questions tend to be off-topic too most of the time...


Remove those programming-language related tags because we don’t really need them

They are useless (until counter example is provided).

It looks like this has been executed: I fail to find any programming-language related tags on crypto.se at time of writing.

Could we add notation for platform implementation specific questions? An example is library quirks mentioned by SEJPM above.
